# How to get pyarmor to work with .pyw scripts?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, cmd, obfuscation, pyarmor

I am trying to run this command:

```
pyarmor pack -e " --onefile --icon icon.ico" MyScript.pyw
```

With the .pyw extension, however pyarmor responds with:

```
INFO     PyArmor Trial Version 6.8.0
INFO     Python 3.9.7
ERROR    No project MyScript.pyw found
```

Now I know my file definitely exists, I have checked multiple times. However, I think pyarmor is just not recognizing it. Any help would be appreciated.